# Is there a way to keep formatting (rows and column size) and locked cells on a macro?

Tags: excel, vba

Below is the code I am using. I would like to edit it so that it will maintain column and row size as well as maintaining locked cells on the split workbooks. Currently the codes splits the original file but doesn't maintain formatting which requires a lot of manual work to make the files shareable.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SplitSheetIntoMultipleWorkbooksBasedOnColumn()
    Dim objWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim nLastRow As Long, nRow As Long``
    Dim nColCnt As Long, rowRng As Range
    Dim strColValue As String, savePath As String
    Dim objDic As Object, i As Long
    Dim varColValues As Variant
    Dim varColValue As Variant
    Dim objExcelWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim objSheet As Worksheet
    Const H_ROW = 8 ' header row#
    Set objWorksheet = ActiveSheet
    With objWorksheet
        nLastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        nColCnt = .Cells(H_ROW, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Set objDic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        ' Loop through data
        For nRow = H_ROW + 1 To nLastRow
            strColValue = Trim(.Range("B" & nRow).Value)
            If Len(strColValue) > 0 Then
                ' Store data range in Dict
                Set rowRng = .Cells(nRow, 1).Resize(1, nColCnt)
                If objDic.Exists(strColValue) Then
                    Set objDic(strColValue) = Union(rowRng, objDic(strColValue))
                Else
                    Set objDic(strColValue) = rowRng
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With
    varColValues = objDic.Keys
    For i = LBound(varColValues) To UBound(varColValues)
        varColValue = varColValues(i)
        Set objExcelWorkbook = Workbooks.Add
        Set objSheet = objExcelWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        objSheet.Name = objWorksheet.Name
        ' Copy header and above rows
        objWorksheet.Rows("1:" & H_ROW).Copy objSheet.Range("A1")
        ' Copy data rows
        objDic(varColValue).Copy objSheet.Cells(H_ROW + 1, 1)
        ' Save the new workbook in a specific location
        savePath = "file path" ' Specify the save path here
        objExcelWorkbook.SaveAs savePath & varColValue & ".xlsx"
        objExcelWorkbook.Close
    Next
End Sub
```

I have tried researching and haven't come up with anything that was helpful

Comment: I think the question is missing some context, are you trying to make the same (hard-coded) formatting every time or copy from source?

Comment: By "formatting" are you just referring to column width or also Bold Italic, bg Colors etc?

Comment: Yes, all formatting. Currently font, cell specific formatting, and conditional formatting is transferring over. What is not coming over is freeze panes, column/row size and locked cells. Filtering is also not coming over but that would be a nice to have.

Comment: would it be easier to duplicate the workbook and just delete the things you don't want?

Comment: No, because there are 4000 + lines and the workbook is being split into 50+ individual files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes:

- Coping the entire rows keeps the row height
- Use `xlPasteColumnWidths` to keep the column width
- `freeze panes` is a setting of Window. You can't copy it over. If all files have same setting, you could add code to apply freeze panes before save the file.
- The status of `locked` is copied over base on my testing (M365).

```vb
    varColValues = objDic.Keys
    For i = LBound(varColValues) To UBound(varColValues)
        varColValue = varColValues(i)
        Set objExcelWorkbook = Workbooks.Add
        Set objSheet = objExcelWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        objSheet.Name = objWorksheet.Name
        ' Copy header and above rows
        objWorksheet.Rows("1:" & H_ROW).Copy objSheet.Range("A1")
        ' ** Copy over column width
        objWorksheet.Range("A1").Resize(1, nColCnt).Copy
        objSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, _
            SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False        
        ' ** Copy rows to keep row height
        objDic(varColValue).EntireRow.Copy objSheet.Cells(H_ROW + 1, 1)
        ' Save the new workbook in a specific location
        savePath = "file path" ' Specify the save path here
        objExcelWorkbook.SaveAs savePath & varColValue & ".xlsx"
        objExcelWorkbook.Close
    Next
```

---

Update:

> Question: all cells are locked except Col T, U, V

```vb
    varColValues = objDic.Keys
    For i = LBound(varColValues) To UBound(varColValues)
        varColValue = varColValues(i)
        Set objExcelWorkbook = Workbooks.Add
        Set objSheet = objExcelWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        objSheet.Name = objWorksheet.Name
        ' Copy header and above rows
        objWorksheet.Rows("1:" & H_ROW).Copy objSheet.Range("A1")
        ' ** Copy over column width
        objWorksheet.Range("A1").Resize(1, nColCnt).Copy
        objSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, _
            SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False        
        ' ** Copy rows to keep row height
        objDic(varColValue).EntireRow.Copy objSheet.Cells(H_ROW + 1, 1)
        ' *** Update
        objSheet.Cells.Locked = True 
        objSheet.Range("T:T,U:U,V:V").Locked = False
        objSheet.Protect Password:="Enter your Password"
        ' Save the new workbook in a specific location
        savePath = "file path" ' Specify the save path here
        objExcelWorkbook.SaveAs savePath & varColValue & ".xlsx"
        objExcelWorkbook.Close
    Next
```

Comment: It's a typo. Try `objWorksheet.Range("A1").Resize(1, nColCnt).Copy`. Which row throws 1004?

Comment: that fixed the issue. the only thing not working is the maintaining locked cells

Comment: Do you have a rule about the lockec cells? eg. all cells are locked except Col E, G, K

Comment: Yes, all cells are locked except Col T, U, V

Comment: Was looking at adding this but not sure where to add it in the code ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="Enter your Password"
Worksheets("Enter your sheet name").Range("A1:I50").Locked = True
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="Enter your Password"

Comment: I've updated the code. The activesheet is a new created sheet. You don't need to unprotect it before processing.

Comment: getting an error on this line: objWorksheet.Cells.Locked = True (had to update objSheets to ObjWorksheet)                                                                                      
 Error Message: Unable to set the Locked property of Range Class.

Comment: No. It is `objSheet`. See the section `' *** Update`.

Comment: The formulas are only being pasted on the last file created, I can't figure out how to fix this. Tried revised code posted here (not sure if this is allowed) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78022488/formula-is-only-showing-up-on-the-last-workbook-created-from-the-split-workbook